# Changing data set name by using loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to change the name of dataset by using loop but it did not work.
Below is my code:

```
    for ( i in 6) {
    nam<-paste("CAT", i,sep=".")
    assign(nam, data_out[i])
    }
```

Only "CAT.6" was assigned to the data set. What about others i ?

Many thanks in advance !

Regards,
Bartek

Comment: for (i in 1:6) solves it

Comment: Also, [consider using `lists`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061).

Comment: @Usobi, by the way, I'll remove my answer below if you want to get the rep for it. Just let me know.

Comment: @TARheman nah its ok

Answer (score 1):

As [Usobi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1916950/usobi) said, your loop has an error. Change the loop to be `for(i in 1:6)` and it will work. Why? Because `for(i in 6)` tells R to iterate i through the set consisting of 6, hence, you get one output (CAT.6).